# How to use react-swipeable-views with react-router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, react-swipeable-views

I am making a small react project with [Material UI](https://mui.com/) and [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/).
I want to implement a tab system with transitions following the [documentation](https://mui.com/components/tabs/#full-width). To do so, I use [`react-swipeable-views`](https://react-swipeable-views.com/).

**I have two `<Route />` and I would like to render them based on the current location AND have a sliding transition when switching from one to the other.**

My code is as follows but it doesn't work because the `<Route />` elements are not rendered inside a `<Routes />` element.

```js
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(location.pathname);

  return (
    <>
      <Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={(e, val) => setValue(val)}
        indicatorColor="secondary"
        variant="fullWidth"
        textColor="inherit"
      >
        <Tab value="/" label="Reference" component={RouterLink} to="/" />
        <Tab value="/quiz" label="Quiz" component={RouterLink} to="/quiz" />
      </Tabs>
      <Container>
        {/* React wants this to be a <Routes /> but that would mean no transitions :( */}
        <SwipeableViews>
          <Route path="/" element={<div>reference</div>} />
          <Route path="/quiz" element={<div>quiz</div>} />
        </SwipeableViews>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

To fix this issue I tried using [`react-swipeable-routes`](https://github.com/sanfilippopablo/react-swipeable-routes) with provides a `<SwipeableRoutes/>` element which is a merge of `<Routes />` and `<SwipeableViews />`. **Unfortunately, this component is not compatible with v6 of React Router.**

I tried to implement my own `<SwipeableRoutes />` by inspecting the code of React Router v6, `react-swipeable-views`, and `react-swipeable-routes`. Here is the result I have arrived to:

```js
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import {
  createRoutesFromChildren,
  matchRoutes,
  RoutesProps,
  useLocation,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';

function SwipeableRoutes({ children, location }: RoutesProps) {
  location = location || useLocation(); // Location
  const routes = createRoutesFromChildren(children); // RouteObject[]
  const matches = matchRoutes(routes, location); // RouteMatch[]
  const index = routes.findIndex((route) => route === matches?.[0].route);

  // index + 1 because index equals -1 in case of no matching route.
  return (
    <SwipeableViews index={index + 1}>
      <div>No match!</div>
      {routes.map((route) => (
        <Fragment key={route.path}>{route.element}</Fragment>
      ))}
    </SwipeableViews>
  );
}

export default SwipeableRoutes;
```

My code works but I am not statisfied with it. **How can I improve my component/rewrite it entirely to make `react-swipeable-views` compatible with React Router v6?**

My problems are:
First, `matchRoutes` returns an array of matches, whereas `<Routes/>` only matches and renders one component. Is this safe?
Second, I use `.findIndex()` which has `O(n)` time complexity. Can I do better?
Third, will my component behave correctly when containing or by contained by nested `<Route/>` or `<Routes/>`?
Fourth, I fear my component does not fully implement all the lesser known behaviors and features of regular `<Routes/>` and is overall a hack, instead of a well thought-out React component.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My gut was to hit up the `react-swipeable-routes` library to see if they had updated to support RRDv6 but the last update was 2 years ago so I'm sure the answer is no. I also saw you had [posted](https://github.com/sanfilippopablo/react-swipeable-routes/issues/40) an issue there about 5 minutes before asking here. Unfortunately v6 has a lot of breaking changes from v5. I'm actually surprised this hadn't come up or been filed as an issue with this library before now.